# Does a namespace alias change linkage?

Tags: c++

From my understanding, global variables in a `.cpp` file get externally linked. Suppose there are two source files, `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`:

```
// a.cpp
namespace a_ns
{
  int foo;
}

// b.cpp
namespace b_ns
{
  int foo;
}
```

Now suppose both have right after `namespace ns=a_ns;` and `namespace ns=b_ns;` respectively. Will this trigger any undefined behaviour like there would be (I think) if both `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` just used the same namespace `ns` for `foo`?

Comment: Only variables with external linkage get externally linked. Not all "global variables" need to have external linkage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using different namespaces for `foo`, then you introduce two different variables, i.e. `a_ns::foo` and `b_ns::foo`. Hence, there is no ambiguity, no conflict, and no undefined behaviour - just two different variables just as if you called the one `foo` and the other `bar`.

A namespace alias, even at global scope, does not introduce an ambiguity with other translation units, whereas a duplicate namespace-name would. Confer [namespace aliases in this online c++ standard draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/namespace.alias#4)), which defines uniqueness for `namespace-names` within the program, but uniqueness for `namespace aliases` only within a declarative region:

> **7.3.2 Namespace alias**
>
> A namespace-name or namespace-alias shall not be declared as the name
>   of any other entity in the same declarative region. A namespace-name
>   defined at global scope shall not be declared as the name of any other
>   entity in any global scope of the program. ...

Hence, a namespace alias `namespace ns=a_ns` introduced in `a.cpp` will be "visible" only in `a.cpp`, and `namespace ns=b_ns` introduced in `b.cpp` will be "visible" only in `b.cpp`. So each use of `ns::foo` will unambiguously refer to `a_ns` in `a.cpp` and `b_ns` in `b.cpp`, respectively.

But if you actually define the same namespace for `foo` in two different translation units, e.g. `namespace ns { int foo; }` in both `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`, each individual `.cpp`-file will be compiled correctly, but you will get a linker error, e.g. `duplicate symbol __ZN2ns3fooE in: ../a.o; ../b.o`.

Answer (score 5):

No. Your proposed alias does not change the fact that the variables have qualified names `a_ns::foo` and `b_ns::foo`, which are different.

Comment: but what will happen when you refer to `ns::foo`? (`ns` was the common namespace alias both `ns_a` and `ns_b` aliased to).

Comment: @vsoftco: When you refer to `ns::foo` you refer to whatever variable that corresponds to -- either `a_ns::foo` or `b_ns::foo`, depending on context.

Comment: You cannot have `namespace ns=a_ns;` and `namespace ns=b_ns;` at the same time. Quoting the standard: "In a declarative region, a namespace-alias-definition can be used to redefine a namespace-alias declared in
that declarative region to refer **only to the namespace to which it already refers.**"

Comment: @KerrekSB I thought that was part of what the question was about, namely aliasing 2 namespaces with the same name...